# jsp not setting fields in bean on page reload

Tags: java, jsp, setter

I have a simple jsp with two input fields and when the user gets to the page and enters data into the fields I want a bean to be populated when they click submit.  I want the info from the jsp to be populated in a bean with a set.  On the jsp I use a setproperty but when everything runs the fields are just sent to null.

Jsp:

```
<form method=POST>
    <div id="login" style="text-align: center">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
    </div>
    <div id="password" style="text-align: center">
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div id = "error" style="text-align: center">
        <%logBean.getError();%>
    </div>
    <div id="login" style="text-align: center">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

A simple post happens and thats when I want the bean to be populated

Bean:

```
public class LoginBean {
String password = "";
String username = "";
String error = "";

public void setPassword(String password){
    if(password.equals(null)){
        password = "";
    }
    this.password = password.trim();        
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
    if(username.equals(null)){
        username = "";
    }
    this.username = username.trim();
}
public String getUsername(){
    return username;
}

public void setError(String error){
    this.error = error.trim();
}

public String getError(){
    return error;
}
```

}

Action where I need bean to be used:

```
String username = loginBean.getUsername();
String password = loginBean.getPassword();
```

Stacktrace of error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Actions.LoginAction.verify(LoginAction.java:18)
org.apache.jsp.content.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
```

How do I get the jsp to set the fields using the bean so I can call the values in a different java method?

Comment: Can we see your `loginBean` class? (Note that class names should start with an upper case letter.) Also, you don't seem to be using the bean anywhere.

Comment: can you update your jsp file containing the form tag and the missing password input, please?

Comment: @Hannes Been update with your request

Comment: From your current posted code, it is impossible to replicate the problem. Please give more details about how are you sending the data to your servlet or to another JSP or whichever technology you're using as controller.

Comment: Exception is in `LoginAction.java` at line no. 18. Please share code.